# Динамические добавления слушателей

Tags: javascript

Недавно столкнулся с таким вопросом про добавление динамических слушателей: при нажатии на определённый таргет я меняю содержимое формы через innerHTML, а затем добавляю на все поля (input) слушатели через цикл. Вопрос заключается в следующем: такая практика добавления слушателей является хорошей или плохой? И как лучше добавлять слушатели к динамическим элементам?

Если нужны примеры листингов:
HTML:

```
<div class="select__field" id="select__user">
 <input class="select__radio" type="radio" name="select__radio" id="select-radio-seeker" value="seeker">

 <label for="select-radio-seeker" class="__label" id="label-radio-seeker">Соискатель</label>

 <input class="select__radio" type="radio" name="select__radio" id="select-radio-employer" value="employer">

 <label for="select-radio-employer" class="__label" id="label-radio-employer">Работодатель</label>
</div>

<div class="form__body empty" id="form-body"></div>
```

JS:

```
const createFormBodyInner = (type, formBody) => {
    formBody.classList.remove('empty');
    
    if (type === 'seeker') {
        formBody.innerHTML = `
            <div class="input__field" id="login-field">
             <input type="text" name="user-login" class="__input modern" id="login-input" placeholder="Введите логин" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            // Далее ещё создаются поля
        `;
    } else if (type === 'employer') {
        formBody.innerHTML = `
            <div class="input__field" id="login-field">
             <input type="text" name="user-login" class="__input modern" id="login-input" placeholder="Введите логин" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            // Далее ещё создаются поля
        `;
    }

    return;
}

selectUser.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const target = event.target,

        seeker = document.getElementById('label-radio-seeker'),
        employer = document.getElementById('label-radio-employer'),
        
        seekerInput = document.getElementById('select-radio-seeker'),
        employerInput = document.getElementById('select-radio-employer'),
        
        formBody = document.getElementById('form-body');

    if (target === seeker && !seekerInput.checked) {
        createFormBodyInner('seeker', formBody);

        const selected = document.querySelectorAll('.__input');
        for (let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
         selected[i].addEventListener('input', () => {
          // Здесь другие функции
         })
        }
    } else if (target === employer && !employerInput.checked) {
        createFormBodyInner('employer', formBody);

        const selected = document.querySelectorAll('.__input');
    }
})
```

Comment: зачем добавлять всем если можно добавить один на родительский прочти про делегирование. Если ситуация требует то нет нечего плохого в Динамическом добавлении слушателя

Comment: Родительского инпута, в стандартной и динамической разметках - не имеется, присутствует только массив из таких элементов и так как каждый инпут имеет свою "уникальность" (логин, пароль, имя и др.), то каждому надо добавить обработчик события "input", чтобы значение каждого поля проходило через проверку (функцию) и возвращало определённые данные.

Но про делегирование - спасибо, прочту.